# what's the meaning of samtools mpileup result "^F"

Tags: bioinformatics, fastq

this is a part of samtools mpileup result:

```
chr7    55241514        G       2786    .....................
chr7    55241515        C       2786    .....................
chr7    55241516        C       2786    .....................
chr7    55241517        G       2786    .....................
chr7    55241518        T       2786    .....................
chr7    55241519        G       2786    .$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.
chr7    55241520        G       2776    .....................
chr7    55241521        C       2776    .....................
chr7    55241522        T       2776    .....................
chr7    55241523        G       2774    .....................
chr7    55241524        C       2774    .....................
chr7    55241525        T       2774    .....................
chr7    55241526        G       2723    .....................
chr7    55241527        G       2723    .$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.$.
chr7    55241609        C       7999    ......^F.^F.^F.^F.^F.
chr7    55241610        C       7999    .....................
chr7    55241611        C       7999    .....................
chr7    55241612        A       7999    .....................
chr7    55241613        G       7999    .....................
chr7    55241614        C       7999    .....................
chr7    55241615        T       7999    .....................
chr7    55241616        T       7999    .....................
```

I don't know the meaning of "^F", I have consulted the help of mpileup commander, a symbol ‘^’ marks the start of a read. The ASCII of the character following ‘^’ minus 33 gives the mapping quality. A symbol ‘$’ marks the end of a read segment. and it didn't say anything about "F", does anybody know what's meaning of "F" in this result.

Comment: you could also ask biostar: http://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost found the answer by yourself:

> ... a symbol ‘^’ marks the start of a read. The ASCII of the character following ‘^’ minus 33 gives the mapping quality.

So 'F' encodes the mapping quality of one read starting at that position (I think Steve talks about base call qualities instead). Qualities are [phred scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phred_quality_score), i.e. log-scaled error probabilities: P = 10^(-Q/10). You can derive the numeric value for your quality by checking an ASCII table (e.g. man ascii) and then subtract 33. F translates into 70, which gives a mapping quality of 37. The definition of mapping quality varies per aligner but in theory this means that there is a 10^(-37/10)=0.01% chance of misalignment of that one read starting in that column.

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [fastq format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format#Encoding). Using an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you will see that an 'F' has a decimal value of 70. Therefore, the quality score associated with an 'F' is 70 - 33 which gives you 37.

Assuming your pileup was generated using a dataset with Illumina 1.8+ encoding, the quality score range would be 0 to 41. So 37 is quite a high quality score for that position. From memory:

```
40 would give a base call accuracy of 99.99%
30 would give a base call accuracy of 99.90%
20 would give a base call accuracy of 99.00%
10 would give a base call accuracy of 90.00%
 0 would give a base call accuracy of 00.00%
```